# What should table structure look like when adding open auth login to User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, oauth

I have a Rails app with a User model.  I want to allow users to login with a handful of services.  There are 2 ways that I can think to store this in the database but I'm not sure which is best.  I should note that I would like users to be able to connect with more than one service and link the accounts.

**Method 1:**
For each service, add token/secret fields to the User table.  This seems a bit problematic because what if I want to store, for example, twitter token, twitter secret, twitter screenname, and twitter profile img?  I could see the User table having many unused columns.  There may be extra info I want to store with each service.  It would look something like this:

```
id
twitter_token
twitter_screenname
twitter_secret
twitter_pic
facebook_token
facebook_secret
facebook_pic
facebook_name
google_token
google_secret
google_name
etc.
```

**Method 2:**
Or each user could have many social logins and each social login belong to one user.  Then I would have a table that looked something like

```
user_id
token
secret
social_type  # foreign key to a social_site look up table
social_pic
```

and the social type table would look something like:

```
id
social_site_name
oauth_url
```

The only negative of this approach is that I have to generalize what I will store about all services.  How do you guys do it?  Maybe STI is in order here...where there would be a class for each type of login which inherits from a base login class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

- Each **user** can have many **logins**, each **login** belongs to one **user** only.
- **Logins** are of a specific **type**, one **login** is of one **type** only.
- `SocialLogin` table has fields common to all **login-types**, `Google`, `FaceBook` and `Twitter` tables have fields specific to each one.

[image: login_model_01]

Comment: What did you make the diagram in? That's very nice.